# How to calculate the average of total ratings of 5 stars?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the average rating of total star rating for one restaurant. The customers will rate this restaurant. I made a pivot table for storing customers ratings.

> `The average rating =5`

```
--------
place_ratings
---------------
user_id   place_id rating
   1          1      4
   2          1      3
   5          1      5
```

What is the formula or how can I calculate that in php laravel ?
 
 This is my code:

```
public function placeRating($id)
    {

        $rates = PlaceRating::where('place_id',$id)->select('rating')->get()->toArray();

           $rateArray =[];
           foreach ($rates as $rate)
           {
               $rateArray[]= $rate['rating'];
           }

            $sum = array_sum($rateArray);
            $result = $sum/5;

            return response()->json(['rating'=>$result],200);
    }
```

Comment: `$result = $sum/5;` should be `$result = $sum/count($rateArray);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't take all `place_ratings` records out, if there are thousands+ user rate the restaurant, it will slow your API.

Try to use this query:

```php
PlaceRating::where('place_id',$id)->selectRaw('SUM(rating)/COUNT(user_id) AS avg_rating')->first()->avg_rating;
```

Comment: @Nick I think normally the app will limit one user to rate one place

Comment: @Nick However, if a user makes two reviews, the `place_ratings` will generate two records (two rating and two user_id), the query still works.

Comment: @TsaiKoga how can I return the output of this query?

Comment: @Developer take it like this: `->first()->avg_rating`, I have updated it.

Comment: @TsaiKoga yeah, I think you're right. Anyway this is definitely the better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up. I kept it as a collection to make use of the collection methods:

```
public function placeRating($id)
{
    $ratings = PlaceRating::where('place_id',$id)->get();
    $ratingValues = [];

    foreach ($ratings as $aRating) {
        $ratingValues[] = $aRating->rating;
    }

    $ratingAverage = collect($ratingValues)->sum() / $ratings->count();

    return $ratingAverage;
}
```

Comment: or simply $averageRating = $ratings->avg('rating');